# Concatenate 3 integers to a space deliminated string in Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

I'm currently trying to concatenate 3 integers to a space deliminated string. However, I can't seem to get the correct syntax. Am I missing a certain function that will help me put the string together? Below is the code I'm trying to use that should perform the function.

I'm currently getting the error:

> test.ino: In function 'void conv_display_f(unsigned char*, float*)':
>   test:50: error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned char*' to 'char*'
>   test:50: error: initializing argument 1 of 'int snprintf(char*,
>   size_t, const char*, ...)'

```
float flon = 11.11;
unsigned char lon_digits[10];


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  Serial.println();

}

void loop()
{
  conv_display_f(lon_digits, &flon);


void conv_display_f(unsigned char *loca, float *cord)
{
  int deg, minute, seconds;
  char degC[3], minC[2], secC[3];


  float temp = cord[0];
  deg = floor(temp);
  minute = floor((temp-deg)*60);
  seconds = (((temp-deg)*60)-minute)*60;

  snprintf(lon_digits, sizeof(lon_digits), "%d %d %d", deg, minute, seconds);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use 'snprintf()'?

```
char string[100+1];
...
snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "%d %d %d", deg, minute, seconds);
...
```

Or, perhaps:

```
snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "%d %d %d", atoi(deg), atoi(minute), atoi(seconds));
```

or:

```
snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "%s %s %s", deg, minute, seconds);
```

(I am somewhat confused as to where you are intending to do the concatenation in your code).

Comment: So I took your advice and implemented it into the code. Do you know why I'm getting this conversion error? Thank you for the help btw.

Comment: @user3242950, Perhaps I could help further if you would clarify the exact line (in your code above) where the error occurs?  (Although the error indicates it is probably on line 50 of your code, I don't know which line that might be in the code you supplied in the question).